# Python Circular Imports

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

```
# ----- object1.py -----
from object2 import object2

class object1:
    brother = object2()
```

```
# ----- object2.py -----
from object1 import object1

class object2:
    sister = object1()
```

This should be doable. It's not. What's the appropriate way to handle this?

Comment: Thought Experiment: If you boil the problem down to a purely object oriented analogy, what type of relationship could you describe that mimics that behavior? However - If you really boil it down - brothers and sisters don't just spontaneously poof into being. There's usually a parent involved. See where I'm going with this? Another possible solution would be observer pattern where the objects announce themselves, find existing siblings and register for announcements from other new siblings.

Comment: Make it parent and child then :) The idea is back-references, which should be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'from object2 import object2' is an executable statement, and on this line object2 module is loaded to sys.modules. And, since the same is tried in object2 module, and as object2 class is not defined yet, it wont work.

```
 //-->object2.py
 from object1 import object1
 class object2:
     pass

 //-->object1.py
 from object2 import object2
 class object1:
     pass
```

So, Even the above code won't work.

Now, if you modify your code to

```
 //-->object2.py
 import object1
 class object2:
     brother = object1.object1()

 //-->object1.py
 import object2
 class object1:
     sister = object2.object2()
```

If you got through the sequence of execution if we run object2.py

```
  import object1 -->object2.py
  import object2 -->object1.py
  class object1:
      sister = object2.object2() //->it will give error here, as object2 module doesn't have object2 defined yet
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is a bit harder than the usual circular import problems. To execute the class statement that defines `object1`, you need to already have defined `object2`, but to execute the class statement that defines `object2`, you need to already have defined `object1`. You can work around this:

`object1.py`:

```
class object1(object):
    pass

import object2

object1.brother = object2.object2()
```

`object2.py`:

```
class object2(object):
    pass

import object1

object2.sister = object1.object1()
```

This defines enough of `object1` or `object2` to initialize the other class before importing the other module. However, I'd strongly recommend not doing this. Circular dependencies are a headache no matter what language you're working in, and when they depend subtly on initialization order like this, they only get worse.

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-have-modules-that-mutually-import-each-other) have more advice on dealing with circular imports.